# ERROR 704 & 12154 while connecting sqlloader to server

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, tnsnames

I have a oracle database based on a server, and I want to import the data in the tables on the server.
I am trying to use sqlloadr(sqlldr) for inserting all data in the oracle database, which is on localhost and there is no problem in this case, but the problem occurs while I try to connect a web-server(not localhost).

The command that I've used in localhost case:

```
sqlldr <usrname>/<password> control=table.ctl log=table.log ERRORS=25000
```

and following is concerning to web-server

```
sqlldr <usrname>/<password>@LABSERVER control=table.ctl log=table.log ERRORS=25000
```

where I created a tnsnames.ora as following:

```
LABSERVER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = <hostaddress>)(Port = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = <servicename>)
    )
  )
```

but I got this error:

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect:OCIServerAttache [0]

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Any idea will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "where I created a tnsnames.ora which
>   is like following:"

That seems to mean you have posted the TNSNAMES.ORA file from the database server.

Remember you also need a TNSNAMES.ORA file on the client.  Is that correctly configured too?

Comment: the problem was that I had not found the TRASNAMES.ORA, so I created it and I put it in wrong folder, Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue and did not have privileges to modify tnsnames.ora on local, so we had to specify the service in the command line like:

sqlldr userid=username/password@\"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myDBHost)(PORT= 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=MYDBSID)))\" Control='mytable.ldr' Log='mytable.log'

thanks to https://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/oracle-using-sqlplus-and-sqlldr-on-databases-without-tnsnames-entry/#comment-700

Answer (score 1):

if your password has a @ character , then sqlldr utility will not work , change ur password it will work
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21347615

Comment: Thanks! Cant belive that was the problem. It happens even when you type the password at prompt.

Comment: The password need to be quoted like \"p@s\$word\"

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error is telling you that given the host, port, protocol and service_name the client could not find a listening Oracle service. Make sure that your hostname is valid (e.g., you can ping it), that the listener is listening on 1521, and that the service_name in the server database is really the name you specified. You can verify it by issuing this command in sqlplus:

```
SHOW PARAMETER service_names
```

which tells you what the database is registering itself as with the listener.

Answer (score 0):

For those, like me, who found this thread.

One thing to check: file permissions on the tnsnames.ora file.

For clients on the same machine yet not part of the DBA group and with ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BIN set correctly subject error was reported.  File permissions of the tnsnames.ora file precluded world read; as the tnsnames.ora file could not be read 704 / 12514 thrown as service name could not be resolved.

From command prompt: chmod 644 $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora